# Silent installation by using Powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install one client's software by using  PowerShell silent scripting. Below is the script which I have created and its not working and throwing errors like below:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again

Is the below line correct or any mistake in this     Here I am getting issue.

```
$Args = @("/S", "/L1033", -INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION, START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\Software\production\)
```

Full script:

```
$INSTALLDIR = "C:\Software\Software.exe"
$Args = @("/S", "/L1033", -INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION, START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\Software\production\)
$logfile = "D:\BACKUP\Install_Logfile.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    $exitcode = (Start-Process $Installer -ArgumentList $Args -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode    
    if ($exitcode -eq 0) {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Completed Successfully')
    } else {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Failled')
    }
} catch {
    "$_" | Out-File $logfile -Append
    {[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Failled')}
}
```

---

**Edit:**

```cs
$Installer = "C:\OTE\OTE.exe"
$params = @("/S", "/L1033", "-INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION", "-START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\OTE\production\")
$logfile = "C:\Install_Logfile.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

& $Installer @params
if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    [Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Completed Successfully')
} else {
    "$_" | out-file $logfile -append
    [Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Failled')
}
```

In the above script I am getting the error like below,

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Comment: Put all $args element in quotes. This line should throw an error at the moment

Comment: Its not showing any message also..the message box code is correct rite..?

Comment: Run only this line of code in your ise $Args=@("/S", "/L1033", -INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION, START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\Software\production\) , it will throw an error

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you may want to fix in your code:

- `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0). Don't try to overwrite it. Use a different variable name, e.g. `$params`. As others have already mentioned, put the parameters in quotes when defining the array.
- Unless you have specific reasons to use `Start-Process` it's easier to use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) and [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0).
- External programs don't throw PowerShell exceptions, so using `try`/`catch` on them is pointless.
- PowerShell automatically records the exit code of an external program in the automatic variable `$LastExitCode`.

```bsh
$installer = 'C:\Software\Software.exe'
$params = '/S', '/L1033', '-INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION',
          'START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\Software\production'

& $Installer @params
if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    [Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Completed Successfully')
} else {
    [Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation Failled')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I have some confusion here is that "-INSTALL_TYPE"                              
will work in powershell script as it is default switch of the software which I am installing.

Comment: Yes I have tried. but below error I am getting.. 
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Comment: The call operator doesn't have a parameter `ArgumentList`. if he code you posted is really giving you that error then it's coming from your executable. We can't help you with that without knowing what exactly it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your items need to be within quotes when creating an array:

```
$Args=@("/S", "/L1033", "-INSTALL_TYPE=PRESERVE_VERSION", "START_MENU=AStartMenuFolder\Software\production\")
```

Comment: -INSTALL_TYPE and START_MENU switches are correct..??

Comment: We don't know what software you're installing (`C:\Software\Software.exe`) and switches can be specific to individual installers.