# Get $LastExitCode from robocopy result and output to file

Tags: powershell, logging, output, robocopy

How do I get the `$LastExitCode` from `robocopy` result in PowerShell and output it to file?

This is what I tried:

```
$source = "E:\LOShare\process\data\attachments"

$day = (Get-Date).Day
"Day: " + $day

$month = (Get-Date).Month
"Month: " + $month

$year = (Get-Date).Year
"Year: " + $year

$destination = "F:\Attachments\" + $year + "\" + $month
"Destination: " + $destination

$parameters = "/mov /minage:" + $year + $month + $day + "/s"

$rc = Start-Process robocopy   $source $destination $parameters -Wait

if ($LastExitCode -lt 8) {
    $outputFileSuccess = "F:\Attachments\RobocopySuccess" + $day + $month + $year + ".txt"

    Write-Host "Robocopy succeeded"
    GetProcess | robocopy Out-File -FilePath $outputFileSuccess
} else {
    $outputFileError = "F:\Attachments\RobocopyError" + $day + $month + $year + ".txt"
    Write-Host "Robocopy failed with exit code:" $LastExitCode
    GetProcess | robocopy Out-File -FilePath $outputFileError
}
```

Comment: What is `GetProcess | robocopy Out-File ...` supposed to do? `robocopy` should be invoked in the line before the `if`. PowerShell then automatically populates the variable `$LastExitCode` with the exit code of the program. Beware, though, that `robocopy` exit codes 1 through 7 are non-error status codes, so your check should probably be `if ($LastExitCode -lt 8)`.

Comment: Actually exit codes between 1 and 7 are non-error codes. Exit code 8: Some files or directories could not be copied and the retry limit was exceeded.

https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Comment: I believe that's what I wrote.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes the command is invoked before the if statement, but I only posted the relevant part. Added all code in question.

Comment: `$rc = Start-Process robocopy ...` -> `& robocopy ...`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45835014/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `-lt 8` gets the error codes? Then to output to text file it would be something like: `$LastExitCode | out-file -filepath $outputFileSuccess`

Comment: `-lt 8` covers the *non-error* status codes. But yes, `$LastExitCode | Out-File ...` would write the exit code to a file. However, why don't you let `robocopy` handle the logging by itself (`/log:`)?